# How to return Uri of already existing media file?

Tags: android, uri

in my method i am saving file to sdcard and return Uri

```
String path = "/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";
String resourceEntryName = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(audioResourceId);
String filename = resourceEntryName + ".ogg";

File mediaFile = new File(path, filename);
if (!mediaFile.exists()) {

        saveFile();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, resourceEntryName);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, name);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
        return activity.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
    } else {
        return ???
    }
```

If file exists i want to return Uri of this file, but if i make

```
return MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

i get wrong Uri, because using that Uri i can't set it as ringtone. 
I want to return Uri which i can use to set this sound as ringtone.

I tried 
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(resourceEntryName);
this didn't work too

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this Uri to the *usable* Uri with my little static method:

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Activity activity, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Use it this way:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
Uri uri = FileUtil.getRealPathFromUri(getApplicationContext(), uri);
```